# Chrome Inspector Issue - Tab Headers Being Cut Off

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I use the chrome inspector a lot when I develop. This morning when I opened it up, I saw this:
[image]

Look up at the tab headers in the inspector window, it's being weirdly cut off.
[image]

Here's one with the console tab open, the text in the console tab is experiencing the same issue as the headers.
[image]

I've tried completely closing and reopening chrome. No luck, same issue. I tried using the "Restore defaults and reload" command in inspector setting, closing and reopening chrome. No luck, same issue.

This is driving me crazy, I can't an issue similar to this anywhere. I use the inspector so much while developing, so I really need to find a solution.

I really appreciate anyone's time and help with this issue.

Comment: Looks like a broken system font. Try restarting the computer.

Comment: Shut down, waited 3 minutes, started it back up. Same issue persists. :'(

Comment: I guess the next step is reinstalling Chrome.

Comment: Yes, I had to completely uninstall chrome (including deleting hidden files) and reinstalling chrome. It's a little annoying that I'll never know what caused this issue, but whatevs, I can continue developing. Thanks a lot for your time and advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't know what caused this issue, but my solution was to uninstall and then reinstall Chrome.
I recommend completely uninstalling Chrome, which includes:

- Moving the app from applications folder into trash
- Moving all files under `~/Library/Google/` into trash*
- Moving all files under `~/Library/Application Support/Google/` into trash*
- Emptying you trash folder, so that all the files are truly deleted.

*This solution is for Mac systems, file paths are different for Windows.

After the full uninstall, you can reinstall Chrome as normal (download it from another browser).